# Logstash dynamic elasticsearch hosts output

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, configuration, logstash

I have configured my logstash file like this

```
  input { 
    kafka { 
        topics => [
            ...
        ] 
        bootstrap_servers => "${KAFKA_URL}" 
        codec => "json" 
    } 
  } 

  filter {
        ...
  } 

  output { 
        elasticsearch { 
            index => "logstash-%{organizationId}"
            hosts => ["${ELASTICSEARCH_URL}"]
            codec => "json" 
        } 
        stdout { codec => json }
  }
```

the elasticsearch output url is coming from the environment variable.

I want to improve the behavior of logstash and change dynamically the output server url based on the some info that came in the kafka message

It is possible to do it?

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, simply use one field from the message with this notation `%{message_field}`

Comment: @Val I have tried but I receive this error: 14:55:01.754 [LogStash::Runner] ERROR logstash.agent - Cannot create pipeline {:reason=>"bad URI(is not URI?): ${[dbConnections][es][host]}"}

Comment: and the config that I use is : hosts => ["${[dbConnections][es][host]}"]

Comment: oops, my bad... you cannot do that actually, because the ES client is created once during logstash startup... not on every message received. The index name can be dynamic though

Comment: thanks @Val, let see if I can do a workaround, but that can be a cool feature to add to logstash. :)

Comment: Not sure, it's wise to create a new ES client on each message received...